# CIR model. Is there a closed-form solution or even a good proxy of analytical solution?

Tags: stochastic-processes, numerical-methods, differential-equations, wienerprocess, cox-ingersoll-ross

Is there a closed-form (analytical) solution for the Cox-Ingersoll-Ross SDE
\begin{equation}
dr_t=k_r(\theta_r-r_t)dt+\sigma_r\sqrt{r_t}dW_t\tag{1}
\end{equation}
?
Notice that $\{r_t\}$ is our process of interest, $k_r$ and $\theta_r$ are constant parameters and $dW_t$ denotes Wiener increment.
I would need a closed-form solution of $(1)$ (or even a good analytical proxy) so as to compare it with solution of my numerical simulation of $(1)$. I am aiming at determining the order of accuracy of my numerical solution, so I would need an analytical solution (or something like that) of $(1)$ so as to compute the average error of my simulation code, that is $\mathbb{E}\left(r_t^{TRUE}-r_t^{SIMULATED}\right)$.
Any suggestion or good source?

Comment: There's no closed form solution for the square root diffusion $r_t$ that I know of. You can however write down its (conditional) [moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox%E2%80%93Ingersoll%E2%80%93Ross_model#Properties) in closed-form. Similarly, you can write down closed-form solutions for the prices of [zero coupon bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox%E2%80%93Ingersoll%E2%80%93Ross_model#Bond_pricing) and bond options under the CIR model. You can compare both the moments and the prices with your simulation results.

Comment: Also asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3782360/cir-model-is-there-a-closed-form-solution-or-even-a-good-proxy-of-analytical-so